# Are there origin stories similar to what is seen in the Avengers movie trailer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012

Realizing that Marvel is using movies to re-invent the universe in various ways, and the assembled Avengers in this new origin movie are a different line-up than the original origin  and some of the others I'm already familiar with, I'd like to read up on possible arcs that may be related based on what we know from the recent trailers.

The original origin story did feature Loki, but the story itself way underwhelming compared to the trailers we've seen.

Is there an origin story for the Avengers that feature Loki as a principal participant with the same general level of global impact the movie trailer portrays?

Comment: I'd caution answers of this; whilst this is asking about a future event ti should still be useful in the future and we can find some stuff out about the film from the trailer.

Comment: @Pureferret - A very good point. I changed the question title to help distinguish this differently from a viable future question about actual background of the movie once it's released and viewed. Hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Marvel Universe continuity 616, the canon universe of the Marvel Comics, no, the origin story of the Avengers does not have the city spanning effect that the trailers for the movie are currently showing. The origin of the Avengers did have Loki as the primary instigator, but there was no city destroying event as the backdrop.

There are echoes of the Ultimates continuity (Marvel Earth Timeline #1610) where Nick Fury is a Black man, and there were no other superheroes until the late 20th Century, with the exception of Captain America, who was still created during World War II.

The closest analog I can find is an animated television series, *The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes*, which premiered on October 20, 2010. The animated series starts with a storyline similar to the movie except the enemy is Kang the Conquerer, a time-traveler who comes to the past in order to prevent events which lead to the destruction of his future. The first two episodes show a war across the city of New York very similar to the trailers for the new movie coming out.

I am certain this is not an accident as they wanted an event to be large enough to challenge the physical capabilities of the three most powerful Avengers, Thor, Hulk and Iron Man, as well as an event filled with military operations which allow Captain America, Black Widow, Hawkeye, Nick Fury and the organization of SHIELD to be involved.

Comment: *The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes* is a good watch, to be sure, and scale appropriate for the movie, but I think they'd be hard pressed to adapt the Kang storyline itself to featuring Loki (without Kang)... but they *have* be rather hush about who Loki's friends are. Given the timing of cartoon series, similarity of the hero line-up and composition of their related origins (which are close to their individual movies iirc), you could be right! It's a great thought. At the very least, it's worth re-watching. =) Thanks!

Comment: I believe I stumbled upon corroborating information based on your lead regarding the animated series, and it does make sense overall. Thanks again!

Comment: Capitalizing “black” goes against the typical standard used by media outlets and outlined by the AP Stylebook (which DCentric abides by). But some believe both “black ” and “white” should be capitalized to defer respect and equity — Hispanic and Native American are capitalized, after all. Most American whites think of themselves as Italian-American or Jewish or otherwise relating to other past connections that Blacks cannot make because of the familial and national disruptions of slavery. So to me, because Black speaks to an unknown familial/national past it deserves capitalization.

Comment: That's fine; I almost left "Black" capitalized in my edit, but "Black Man" was right out -- especially in this context, where it would look like the least inspired superhero name ever. ;)